# R: If condition is not met for rows in data frame 1 and data frame 2, remove rows in both data frames

Tags: r

Imagine I have two data frames, 'first' and 'second':

```
x = c(12,14,11,15,10)
y = c(25,22,20,21,23)
id = c(1,1,1,2,2)
first = data.frame(x,y,id)
x1 = c(32,34,31,35,30)
y1 = c(45,42,40,41,43)
id1 = c(1,1,1,1,2)
second = data.frame(x1,y1,id1)
colnames(second) <- c("x", "y", "id")
```

Here 'id' denotes a group number. In this example, I would like to be able to count the number of rows by 'id'.  If the number of rows for a given 'id' in either data frame is less than 2, then I would like to remove those rows from both data frames.

In other words, if any group has less than 2 rows, them remove that group from both data frames.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I guess you mean `first  = data.frame(...)` on the 4th line?

Comment: yep...sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(first, key = 'id')
dt2 = data.table(second, key = 'id')

throw.away.ids = c(dt1[, .N < 2, by = id][(V1), id],
                   dt2[, .N < 2, by = id][(V1), id])

dt1[!J(throw.away.ids)]
dt2[!J(throw.away.ids)]
```

I filtered all of the ids that need to go from both data sets, then combined them together and filtered them out. Note, I didn't make `throw.away.ids` unique, because it doesn't matter for the next join operation.

Comment: Beautiful...this is really swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the trick:

```
id.first = unique(first$id)
id.second = unique(second$id)
ids = NULL
for(i in unique(first$id)){
    if(i %in% id.second && sum(first$id == i) >= 2 && sum(second$id == i) >= 2){
      ids = c(ids, i)
    } 
}
first = first[first$id %in% ids,]
second = second[second$id %in% ids,]
```